# AquaData Oracle create procedure error 00900

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, aqua-data-studio

I'm an Oracle newbie (SQLServer background) and I'm having a heck of a time creating a stored procedure to return a record set.  The below code [names obfuscated, they're named better than that in real life...] seems to match other examples I've seen here and elsewhere, but Aquadata returns an error for "*FAILED to execute EXPLAIN plan: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement*" when I run the `CREATE`.  When I try to execute the stored procedure, I get "*00905 - missing keyword*".

For the life of me, I can't see the syntax error.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_MyProc (
p_id in number,
prc out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN prc FOR
        SELECT mm.fld1, mm.fld2, mm.fld3, mm.fld4, mm.fld5, mm.fld6, mm.fld7, mm.fld8, mm.fld9, loa.fld1 FROM DB.tbl1 mm
        INNER JOIN db2.tbl2 loa ON mm.fld1 = loa.fld1
        WHERE mm.fld5 = '44,53' AND mm.fld1 =p_id;
 
END P_MyProc;
```

Comment: SQL and PL/ SQL are different, and you can't get an explain plan for PL/SQL. It isn't clear if that's happening automatically or if you're running this incorrectly. Anyway, [does this help](https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation16/page/10/Procedure-Function-Package-Editor)?

Comment: Well, the LINK didn't help but your answer did lead me to the source of the error - for some reason Aquadata was setup to always show an execution plan / explain table.  When I got rid of that, the errors cleared up.  Thanks!